# Validation not happening on HandleSubimt inside react form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

As stated I have some fields that need to be validated and it's just not happening on react-form. I'm following the course "Modern React with Redux" and I have the following code with a redux form which must be validated for empty values:

```
import React from "react";
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';

class StreamCreate extends React.Component {
    renderInput({input, label, meta}){
        console.log(meta)
        return (
            <div className="field">
                <label>{label}</label>
                <input {...input}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

    onSubmit(formValues){
        console.log(formValues);
    }
    
    render(){
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)} className="ui form">
                <Field name="title" component={this.renderInput} 
                    label="enter title"
                />
                <Field name="description" component={this.renderInput} 
                    label="enter description"
                />
                <button className="ui button primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
} 

const validate = (formValues) => { // This is not running!
    const errors = {};

    if (!formValues.title){
        errors.title = "you must enter a title";
    }
    if (!formValues.description){
        errors.description = "you must enter a description";
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'streamCreate',
    validate // I followed the example to the T and checked the documentation
})(StreamCreate);
```

Here's the documentation:

https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/examples/syncvalidation/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe try using a functional component for `StreamCreate`?

Comment: I dont see you are returning the errors in the `validate` function. so redux-form will not be aware of these. can you try to add the return statement ?